# is there a way to merge two filtered rows in advanced editor in powerbi. I want to merge filtered row 1 and filtered row 2

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\Users\swaip\Downloads\raw_data_metrics.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=9, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]), 
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]), #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"KEY", type text}, {"VALUE", type number}, {"MODEL_NAME", type text}, {"METRIC_GROUP", type text}, {"COUNTRY", type text}, {"DATE_TIME", type datetime}, {"RUN_ID", type text}, {"ENV", type text}, {"_METADATA_FILE_NAME", type text}}), 
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each true), 
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", 
latest = List.Max(#"Filtered Rows"[DATE_TIME]) in each Text.StartsWith([METRIC_GROUP], "prediction") and [DATE_TIME] = latest),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Text.StartsWith([METRIC_GROUP], "training")) in #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
combined = #"Filtered Rows1" & #"Filtered Rows2",
```

or

```
combined = Table.Combine({#"Filtered Rows1",#"Filtered Rows2"}),
```

will append the second to the first if they have similar column structure.